# Shell script for hbase commands | count 'table'

Tags: unix, hbase, sh, hbase-shell

I am trying to get the counts of a list of tables in hbase using the count command. I am currently placing all command in input.txt.

Sample input

```
count  'test.table1', INTERVAL => 10000000, CACHE => 10000000
count 'test.table2', INTERVAL => 10000000, CACHE => 10000000
```

Command

```
hbase shell ./input.txt
```

Is there a way to write a shell script so that I can run on nohup.out and get the output like as below via shell script so that I can run it for any number of tables :

```
table1,500000
table2,300
```

Appreciate any help in this regard

Answer (score 2):

This bit of code might help you to get the count of records for all tables in HBase.

`#!/bin/bash
echo 'list' | hbase shell | sed -e '1,/TABLE/d' -e '/seconds/,$d' |
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
        echo "count '$line'" | hbase shell | tail -n 1  | xargs echo "$line,">> ./tableCount.log
done`

Tested this in HBase 1.1.8, output will be stored in tableCount.log.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info.. so are we passing the list of table names as input in a file?

Comment: No, the above code first gets the list of tables in HBase and then gets the no. of rows for each table.